# SQL Server 2008 data migration to another SQL 2008 server

Tags: sql

I am currently running SQL server 2008 (SQLserverold) which homes databases for systemn center Service Manager 2012 Datawarehouse. This server is very old and needs to be decommisioned. Prior to decomissioning the serve, the databases have to be migrated to another clustered SQL server with two nodes(SQLServer1 and SQLserver2). 
I am not a DB admin no experience in SQL, and I have been given the task of migrating the Databases on the old server to the new custered environmnet. Can some point me to the right direction as to how i could do this. Step by step instruction would be helpful.

Thank you in advance

confy

Comment: "not a DB admin, no experience with SQL, please give me step-by-step instructions" You just violated just about every rule we have on this site. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Connect to the old server.

Either:
Backup the current databases:
 - Right Click on the Database
 - Select Backup

Or:
I assume there will already be a maintenance plan in place taking backups, find where this is putting its backups (.bak files).

3. Copy the backup files to the new server.
4. Connect to the new server in SQL Management Studio.
5. Right click on Databases and select restore.

I would recommend that on the new server you:

1. Split the log and data files onto separate disks and spindles to ensure there is no blocking.
2. Setup a maintenance plan to ensure you have frequent backups of your data. (Daily ideally), you will also need to make sure that this data is copied of the server if the server completely fails.
3. Put the Data and Log files into separate subfolders. Not necessary but easier to manage.

However, seeing as you have no idea how to do this and this is a very simple job, I would definitely recommend getting a professional in to do this for you.